# In Scene2D, does Actor.hasActions() no longer exist?

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

Eclipse does not allow me to do

while (actor.hasActions()){}

saying it's undefined for type actor, but the libgdx API still has it as one of an Actor object functions.

Answer (score 2):

According to the source history on [`Actor`](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/commit/916a05c96a1be03fa1390bdfce02ec84a4bd96f8) ,  the `hasActions` method was added 7 days ago. Get latest and I think it should work for you.

Answer (score -1):

You can instead do:

```
actor.getActions().size != 0
```